# How can I measure the precision and Recall?

Tags: similarity, semantic-similarity, precision-recall-curve

I did semantic search using query and the total relevant documents should be 12 documents but my model retrieve 5 relevant documents only so the irrelevant are 7 documents. how can i calculate the precision and recall ?